# how to verify that a set of matrices forms a group under multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For a given set of matrices, how can i verify that they form a group under multiplication? 
I am looking for specific conditions so that i can insert them in a code to verify whether any set of matrices forms a group under multiplication.

---

Exemple:
''' The multiplicative group of Weyl $\mathcal{G}_{w2}$ has 12 cosets $\{C_0,C_2\dots,C_{11}\}$, each one containing 16 unitary (hence invertible) matrices, where the first coset $C_0$ is defined as:
\begin{equation*}
    C_0= \left \{    \alpha \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \pm 1       \end{bmatrix} \ , \ \alpha   \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ \pm1 & 0       \end{bmatrix}    \right \} 
\end{equation*}
with $\alpha \in \{ +1,-1,+i,-i \}$. All the 12 cosets are derived from $C_0$ as follows: 
\begin{equation*}
    C_k = a_k C_0 \ \forall k=0,1,\dots ,11 
\end{equation*}
where $a_k$ can be grouped into two sets, the first one being $\{a_0,a_1,\dots,a_5\}$ where:
\begin{align*} 
  a_0 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 &  1\end{bmatrix} \   
  a_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 &  i\end{bmatrix} \ 
  a_2 = {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\\ 
   a_3 = {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ i & -i  \end{bmatrix}\ 
  a_4 = {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \begin{bmatrix}1 & i \\ 1 & -i \end{bmatrix} \ 
  a_5 = {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \begin{bmatrix}1 & i \\ i & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*} 
 The second set $\{a_6,a_7,\dots a_{11}\}$ is given by: $a_{k+6}= \eta a_k$, with $\eta =(1+i)/\sqrt{2} \ \ \forall k =0,1,\dots ,5$,

leading to a total of 192 unitary matrices.'''

---

i understand that the example given forms a group under multiplication, i am looking to verify this using code so i need precise conditions that allows this set to become a group.

Thanks

Comment: A set of cosets of a subgroup is a group itself if and only if the original subgroup is normal. So you have to check whether $C_0$ is normal in $\mathcal{G}_{w2}$.

Comment: You require tools from computational group theory such as in the book of D. Holt.